# storm list doesn't show running topology?

Tags: apache-storm

Nimbus and Supervisor is on the same machine. I'm running my jar on storm with 'bin/storm XX.jar XX.XX' and stdout shows that this topology is running well.

But while I use 'bin/storm list', no infomation of my topology is show.

Comment: Are you using the Storm UI, and what does it show?

Comment: I've solve this problem. I run the topology in a local cluster according to the tutorial. After I changed to the cluster mode, the storm ui shows the topology status.

Comment: @FrankYao then answer yourself below and accept answer, so we can deem this question resolved.

Comment: Did you start the topology using `storm activate topology-name`?